# Running my file from the terminal Pycharm

Tags: python, terminal, console, pycharm

I am trying to do something that I am following in a tutorial.
The code is for testing a dictionary and it is as it follows:

```
cd = ConfigDict('config_file.txt')


if len(sys.argv) == 3:

    key = sys.argv[1]
    value = sys.argv[2]
    print('writing data:  {}, {}'.format(key, value))

    cd[key] = value

else:

    print('reading data')
    for key in cd.keys():
        print('   {} = {}'.format(key, cd[key]))
```

To test one can enter the name of the file alone or with the testing cases direct to the terminal as you can see below:

[image: here]
I am using Pycharm and I did not find a way to do the same as it is done on this tutorial. I tried to **Open on Terminal** and to change

*Run->Edit Configurations -> Run with python console

or

Run->Edit Configurations -> Emulate terminal in output console*

[image]

I did not figure how to run it with the python file and the inputs to tests. Any hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: you can run `python main.py < testcasesfile.txt `in the terminal right? i didnt understand whats the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to `run/debug configurations`, then enter the command line settings/parameters in the appropriate field:

[image]

You have a similar option in the tests settings to add parameters to test runs.

Comment: But following parameters like he did is not possible, right? Thank you very much for your answer and the screenshot

Comment: I can only run one parameter test at a time? not following, I guess. Still great to see this solution.

Comment: You can probably have a sequence of parameters; maybe white-space, or comma separated? I have not tried.